# SSIS: LTRIM and Concatenate two columns

Tags: ssis, expression, concatenation

I have an issue concatenate two columns, where one includes a lot of zeros which I would like to delete.

(SSIS Derived Column transformation)

```
Ex. Company + 00034535
```

I want to concatenate there columns so I'll have the result: `Company34535`

What I have tried (which doesn't work)

```
(DT_WSTR,100)LTRIM(Company+ Nr)
```

Any ideas how to solve this with an expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this expression:

```
Company + RIGHT(Number,LEN(Number) - 3)
```

Note in my case `Number` is the name of the second column, also take in account that it will work if `Number` column always have three leading zeros.

**UPDATE:** Number column doesn't follow the three zeroes pattern.

Use this expression:

```
Company + REPLACE(Number,"0","")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse, any suggestions if the leading zeros vary?

Comment: @user3052850, you are welcome!. If my answer replied to your question. you can select it as the correct answer. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)